# Inverse trig and trigh in integration?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

[image]

I have just done part (iii) of this question and can get the right answer but am a bit confused why do we take arcosh i.e. just the principle value of cosh and not the other value. I presume this is the case with trig? also in this question they have ignored the negative square root when using a trigh identity please explain why??  (a=.5, b-0.25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is admittedly traditional to write the substitution as "Let $2x=\cosh u$."  But for completeness it should have been "Let $2x=\cosh u$, where $u\ge 0$." (Or else, conceivably, where $u\le 0$.)

Then $u=\text{arccosh}(2x)$ is the only possibility, the alternative is not available. Or else, more directly, we could have described the substitution as $u=\text{arccosh}(2x)$, in which case there is no ambiguity of sign.

Whenever we make a substitution that involves a function which is not one to one, we must restrict the domain.

Comment: Thanks bit what about the square root.? If you work thru the qestion you need to take a square root and ignore the negtive version is this for the same reson??

Comment: Yes, during the calculation we need to find the positive $u$ such that $\cosh u=a$. So we are solving $e^u+e^{-u}=2a$. Multiplying by $e^u$, we get the equation $e^{2u}-2ae^u+1=0$, essentially a quadratic. The solutions are $e^u=a\pm \sqrt{a^2-1}$. But one of these (the one with the minus) gives $e^u\lt 1$, so negative $u$. We want the positive $u$, which is $\ln(a+\sqrt{a^2+1}$.